# stripslashes issue

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to condense/improve/optimize this code

```
cleaned = stringwithslashes
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\n", "\n")
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\r", "\n")
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\", "")
```

but the above code does not work correctly

Comment: Uhhh, why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: thats not PHP unless its some templating language...

Comment: Use `r'raw strings'` when you want unescaped backslashes.  And you have syntax errors in lines 2, 3 (no closing quotes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
cleaned = stringwithslashes.decode('string_escape')
```

Comment: Err, what? Reference to this?

Comment: This is only possible with Python 2. With Python 3 it dows not work any more.

Answer (score 1):

for starters your code is missing quotes. Did you tried this?

```
cleaned = stringwithslashes
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\n", "\n")
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\r", "\n")
cleaned = cleaned.replace("\\", "")
```